# Symfony3 Service and Token Storage

Tags: symfony, service

I try to Setup a Service to retrieve a Entity from my Database.
My services.yml looks like this:

```
app.twig_global_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\GlobalExtension
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@security.token_storage" ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And my GlobalExtension like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class GlobalExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $em;
    protected $token_storage;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage $token_storage)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
    }


    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return [
            'userdata' => $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:userdata')->findOneBy(['internalid' => $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getId()]),
        ];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_global_extension';
    }
}
```

It retrieves the Right Entity but my Profiler throws a Error after the page finished loading:

```
BadMethodCallException in GlobalExtension.php line 18:
Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object (null)
```

First of all what is the Problem in this case?

```
$this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getId()
```

It retrieves the Right ID but throws a Error inside the Profiler?

\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager since this gets marked as Deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Call to a member function getUser() on a **non-object (null)**" As your code is `$this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getId()`, `$this->token_storage->getToken()` has to be `null` in order for this error to be true. Looking at the [PHPdoc for this method](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/b5c4b14ce46387314b6bd17f13ac151b446c6847/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.php#L23-L28), you'll see:

```
/**
 * Returns the current security token.
 *
 * @return TokenInterface|null A TokenInterface instance or null if no authentication information is available
 */
public function getToken();
```

In other words, the profiler URL probably isn't behind a firewall and thus `getToken()` has no authentication information and is null.

In your function, make sure you take this case into account and for instance return null when then token is not available.

Comment: it would be cleaner to "detect" the profiler context, no ?

Comment: No, you don't know which pages will use this custom function. There may be more pages that aren't behind a firewall.